# Explode string by semicolon using php's preg_split

Tags: php, regex, string, split, preg-split

I have this string (it's an apple .strings file):

```
/* this is a comment line; it may contain semicolons */
"you have here some text; also may contain semicolons" = "some other text;";

/* this is a comment line; it may contain semicolons */
"you have here some text; also may contain semicolons" = "some other text;";
```

and so on.

I need to split this string after the semicolons at the end of each non-commented line.

If I use `explode(";\n", $string);` may not be accurate as the line could end in a ;(whitespace)(new line)

Update:
The output should be an array. Each element should contain the commented line (if exists) and the quoted strings line.

Comment: From your example .. what is your expected output

Comment: You can use `;\s*\n` to allow whitespaces between the colon and the line end. - or simple match all key/value pairs directly, using `preg_match_all` and `"([^"]+)"\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\*;`. if the values may containt escaped versions of `"` use something like `^"(.*?)"\s*=\s*"(.*?)";\s*\n$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only concerned about the optional whitespace, you might get along with

```
$array = preg_split("/;\s*\n/", $string);
```

`preg_split` takes a regular expression while `explode` takes a string as delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You might be best simply reading the file line by line, testing for comment characters using [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), and using [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) for parsing the file lines rather than regexp

Comment: won't str_getcsv() mess the quoted strings containing semicolons ? I think it will.

Comment: The whole point of using str_getcsv() is that it handles quoted strings correctly